# Prove that the transcendental degree of $k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_r)$ is larger than $n-r$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, dimension-theory-algebra

I am trying to solve the Exercise 1.9 from Hartshorne:

> Suppose the ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $R$ can be generated by $r$ elements.  Show that every irreducible component of $Z(\mathfrak a)$ has dimension $\geq n-r$.

---

I know it is an immediate corollary from Krull's dimension theorem. However, I try to follow the idea given in this [notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/256A/1.1.pdf):

We know the dimension of any component of $Z(\mathfrak a)$ = transcendence degree of its function field, that is, the quotient field of $A(Z(\mathfrak a))$.

I guess this quotient field is 
$$K(k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_r))\cong \, ?.$$
I don't know what the field is. **Please verify or deny this statement.**

If so, this function field contains $x_1, . . . , x_n$ and the algebraic relations between these are a consequence of the $r$ generators
of $a$. Therefore the dimension of any component is at least $n$ minus the number of generators of $\mathfrak a$, that is,  greater than $ n − r$.

Note that here we assume it is true that the transcendental degree of $k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_r)$ is greater than $n-r$, which is intuitionally correct, but **how to prove it**?

Comment: $k(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, if my understanding is correct, is a field. Then going modulo any non-zero element gives you the zero ring.

Comment: @Mohan You are right. Fixed.

Comment: Unless $(f_1,\ldots, f_r)$ is a prime ideal, you can not do what you do, somewhat ambiguous. You can take the total quotient ring which is not a field.

Comment: @Mohan However, if we cannot get some nice result on the quotient field, then we cannot follow the idea involving the transcendental degree...